# Does anyone know how to make the 3 blocks fader in the current spring.io website?

Tags: spring, web

I'd like to know how can I code the 3 blocks fader from the Spring.io website.  Image here: 
[It has a dividing line that changes the image gradually as you move it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC44K.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with simple HTML and javascript code. Here's the complete jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zn3b1hov/34/

Basic Idea is very simple.

**First**, You need 2 SVG images one is colored and another is grayscale. I am using this 2

- [grayscale-image](https://spring.io/img/homepage/diagram-modern-java-gray-9a417697a51646e42df7e9d7f024709d.svg)
- [colored-image](https://spring.io/img/homepage/diagram-modern-java-color-e10b7eec68b1fe60eefeab0cf20a20da.svg)

**Now** Create 2 absolute div one on top of another and use these images as background.

**Then** create a slider as wide as the images. I am using [HTML range type input](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp)

**Finally** change the top div's width according to sliders value.

**Complete HTML, CSS and JS**

```
<style>
    #fader-diagram-your-app {
        position: relative;
        height: 286px;
    }

    #fader-diagram-modern-java-gray {
        position: absolute;
        height: 238px;
        width: 800px;
        margin: 31px auto;
        background: url('https://spring.io/img/homepage/diagram-modern-java-gray-9a417697a51646e42df7e9d7f024709d.svg') no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
    }

    #fader-diagram-modern-java-color {
        position: absolute;
        height: 238px;
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 31px auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 200px;
    }

    #fader-diagram-modern-java-color div {
        position: absolute;
        height: 238px;
        background: url('https://spring.io/img/homepage/diagram-modern-java-color-e10b7eec68b1fe60eefeab0cf20a20da.svg') no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        width: 800px;
    }

    #fader {
        background-color: #34302d;
        width: 6px;
        height: 275px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
    }

    #myRange {
        width: 800px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
    }
</style>

<div id="fader-diagram-your-app">
    <div class="sidebyside" id="fader-diagram">
        <div id="fader-diagram-modern-java-gray"></div>
        <div id="fader-diagram-modern-java-color" style="width: 39.6875px;">
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div id="fader">
        </div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="800" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange">
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var coloredImage = document.getElementById("fader-diagram-modern-java-color");
    var fader = document.getElementById("fader");
    slider.oninput = function() {
        coloredImage.style.width = this.value + "px";
        fader.style.left = this.value + "px";
    }
</script>
```